# Android emulator opens but crashes with following errors

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem with my emulator below:

```
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
ERROR: resizing partition failed with exit code 1
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
### WARNING: unable to configure any DNS servers, name resolution will not work
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer
```

Comment: Edit your VM heap size and make it more than `128 MB`.

Comment: I increased VM heap size to 500MB and another error occured.init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
getGLES1ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 1.x config!
Failed to obtain GLES 1.x extensions string!
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.
Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

Comment: Turn off the GPU emulation in your emulator. That might be help you

Comment: My emulator doesn't show any option for turning of GPU emulation. But it have Option for Selecting either hardware of software as GPU.Thanks for helping me out!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's problem with your GPU.

1. make sure your Graphics Driver is newest version.
2. Uncheck 'Use Host GPU' option in AVD Setting

[image: this image from [This Site](http://ukitech.blogspot.kr/2014/09/android-studio-creating-android-virtual.html)]

This will be help solving your problem.

p.s. this image from [This Site](http://ukitech.blogspot.kr/2014/09/android-studio-creating-android-virtual.html)

Comment: I actually have problem with GPU and uninstalled it and the emulator started. But i couldnot find the use host gpu check box in my android studio 2.1.1. And thanks alot!!!!!