# Ionic cordova run android whitescreen freeze on android emulator

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app using ionic framework with Firebase backend deploy to web application and its works perfectly fine with Firestore. Then, i try to add another platform for android. I already installed Android Studio with sdk and try to connect it to Firebase for example download json file and its sync fine. Then i try to run my project using terminal navigate my ionic project and try ionic cordova add platform "android" then my config.xml in Visual Studio for my project shows this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
etc...
<platform name="android">`
</platform>
etc...
```

After that, i run using terminal `ionic cordova run android -l` and it shows fine no error and automatically open the emulator for Nexus_S_API_23 but then it just blank whitescreen like freeze.. but in my terminal there is a warning that said emulator :

> WARNING: Crash service did not start..

or did i need to change in `'widget id='io.ionic.starter'` to my `firebase android` package name ?

`

Answer (score 0):

Your `widget id` inside app's `config.xml` file must be the same as the package name that you mentioned at the firebase console.
Then, try to add the platform and specific firebase plugins

Comment: only change in widget id ? did i need to put sdk version or version name in config.xml ?

Comment: No need to add SDK version,
your app widget id mentioned in config.xml and package name inside the firebase console must be the same and unique.

Comment: unfortunately, it shows error in my terminal.. i already changed widget id to firebase package name which i found in google-services.json that firebase ask me to download it inside android studio.. my terminal said:' no java files found that extend CordovaActivity'..

Comment: remove your android platform and add an android platform again. then add the firebase plugins

Comment: already removed and add android platform.. then for step 4 which is 'run your app to verify installation' in firebase android setup i skip that step.. then try run in terminal still shows same error

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123931/android-studio-displays-error-on-opening-android-emulator) or 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289202/android-emulator-opens-but-crashes-with-following-errors)
please check if it helps.

Comment: my emulator can run when i remove platform android and re-add again.. but still my emulator said 'application error: connection to the server was unsuccesfull.. is this cause from my environment.ts on my ionic project ? cause coding like firebase api-key for web platform is still there. i want to make my app project can run using browser and android emulator